# what reason show message that "Possibly blocking call in non-blocking context could lead to thread starvation"?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

i using coroutines with spring.

message that "Possibly blocking call in non-blocking context could lead to thread starvation" is show when this code using.

really happen blocking call ?
If happen could you tell me reason ?

Thank you.

```kotlin
suspend fun demo() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val deferred1 = async {
        aRepository.findById("id") // here
    }
    val deferred2 = async {
        bRepository.findById("id") // here
    }

    deferred1.await()
    deferred2.await()
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that this concerns JPA repositories, and they perform work synchronous, and were build for the servlet architecture, which uses blocking code.
Using them with (asynchronous) coroutines triggers this warning. However, I'm not entirely sure if this really is an issue per se.

A solution to suppress this warning is by wrapping the blocking code with `withContext` (also the provided fix-it in my intellij), which suspends the coroutine while the code within the block is executed;

```kotlin
suspend fun demo() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val deferred1 = async {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            aRepository.findById("id") // here
        }
    }
    val deferred2 = async {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            bRepository.findById("id") // here
        }
    }

    deferred1.await()
    deferred2.await()
}
```